# NHibernate LINQ Or HQL

Tags: nhibernate

I have heard about 2 way of querying using hibernate:
NHibernate.Linq and  HQL

NHibernate.Linq or just HQL witch is faster?

Do any one have any other advantage?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Linq to NH that well. Technically is Linq to NH turned into HQL behind the scenes. It provides editor support (auto completion) and compile time validation (e.g. when typo) in contrast to pure HQL, which appears as normal strings to the developer tools.

Similar is QueryOver the successor of Criteria.